# How to Send generated PDF to Mail with PHP?

Tags: php, email, jspdf, html2canvas

I am using this function to generate PDF with JsPDF and Html2canvas in PHP, and successfully generating.
Is it possible to send the generated PDF as an email attachment using PHP instead of downloading?
I have been searching , but wouldnt be able to find any solution

```
function screenshot(){

        var HTML_Width = $(".page_pdf").width();
        var HTML_Height = $(".page_pdf").height();
        var top_left_margin = 15;
        var PDF_Width = HTML_Width+(top_left_margin*2);
        var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width*1.5)+(top_left_margin*2);
        var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
        var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;

        var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height/PDF_Height-5);
        
        window.scrollTo(0,0); 
        html2canvas($(".page_pdf")[0],{scale: 5}).then(function(canvas) {
            canvas.getContext('bitmaprenderer');
          
             window.scrollTo(0,0); 
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt',   [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin,canvas_image_width,canvas_image_height);
            
            for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) { 
                pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
                pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height*i)+(top_left_margin*4),canvas_image_width,canvas_image_height);
            }
            
            pdf.save("liquidacion.pdf");

        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **library**, for example [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and then you can add different **Attachments** like your PDF.

PHPMailer has many more advantages, to name a few:

- SMTP support
- more receivents or BCC (Blind Carbon Copy)
- Protect against header injection attacks